# Example of a function $f$ that doesn't have a local minimum at $0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Give an example of a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that the gradient of $f$ at $0$ is $0$, all eigenvalues of the Hessian $D^2 f(0)$ are nonnegative, but $f$ does not have a local minimum at $0$.

I have been staring at this problem for days and I cannot think of a function, do not know how to go about trying to find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your D2f(0) means the Hessian matrix of $f$ at $(0,0)$. You may just use a standard example in dimension 1 and consider $f(x,y) = x^3$. Then obviously the gradient is $[0,0]^T$ at $(0,0)$ and the Hessian at $(0,0)$ is the zero matrix, which has $0$ (nonnegative) as eigenvalues. But, from the graph of $f$, it is obvious that $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.